# Doctrine subquery in Symfony template

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I want to have a comment box in a Twig template.

```
{% for comment in comments %}

... here ist html code for the box

{% endfor%}
```

How is it possible, to search in every comment entry for other things like sub comments or things like votings and so on? In simple PHP and HTML (not Symfony) it would look something like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
     $sub_query= "SELECT for FROM bar WHERE id = $row['id']";
     $query = mysqli_query($db, $sub_query);
     $sub_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
?>
     <div class="comment_box">
        // code for the box like <?= $row['date'] ?> or <?= $row['date'] ?>
        // code for the subqueryed data like <?= $sub_row['voting_rate'] ?> or <?= $sub_row['sub_comment'] ?>
     </div>
<?php
}
```

What is the way to do this with symphony? Can it be that it has to do with Twig Macros or so on?

**More information:**

Here is the simple controller:

```
   /**
 * Lists all Comment entries.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="comment")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $comments = $em->getRepository('AcmeCommentBundle:Comment')->findAll();

    return array(
        'comments' => $comments,
    );
}
```

Comment: Assuming you really do need to execute a query from inside of twig then look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html and scroll down to the section on embedded controllers.  Like @TomToms, if you just need related entities(his solution) or a new embedded query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I wanted to have was an [embedded Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers). So I can do whatever I want to know about the special piece of information even if I don't have a relationship to it in my database.

Answer (score 3):

So what you want is to access the variables of your entity ?
You can simply use `{{ comment.date }}`.

And to access the variables of linked entities you can do `{{ comment.subcomment.date }}` but you need to have a relationship between your comment and subcomment entities set up.

In case of a ManyToOne or ManyToMany (ex: multiple subcomment for a given comment) relationship you can also do things like

```
{% for subcomment in comment.subcomments %}
   {{ subcomment.date }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or if you need a specific subcomment things like

```
{{ comment.subcomments[1].date }}
```

Your question is not very clear sorry if I'm off topic.
In any case I would recommend reading the doc here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/index.html

Comment: Oh thank you. But this was really noch my question. :) A want to know, whether it is possible to fetch data **within the for-circle** of the comment-entity **without a database-relationship**. But thank you.